# Examples of intramolecular hydrogen bonding closing bond angles

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, stereochemistry, hydrogen-bond

Okay, we've established that *intramolecular* hydrogen bonding can exist in molecules, and doesn't always serve the purpose of closing the bond angle at least *relative* to other stereoisomers of the same compound.

Consider *nitrous* acid and its *cis* and *trans* configuration; hydrogen bonding is only a possibility in the *cis* configuration, yet the *cis* conformation has (rather unexpectedly) a larger bond angle than in the *trans* conformation. The same goes for nitric acid.

[Why does nitrous acid exhibit (unexpectedly) different bond angles?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15558/why-does-nitrous-acid-exhibit-unexpectedly-different-bond-angles)

So, are there actually any examples of molecules in which internal hydrogen bonding serves the purpose of closing up the bond angle relative to other conformations of the same molecule?